# 1GB of RAM not usable

Tags: memory, ubuntu-20.04, amd-athlon, dual-core

I just installed another 1GB of RAM to my computer, boot to Ubuntu sucessfully, but it doesn't show the extra GB. So, I took a look into the BIOS, and it shows "Installed Memory: 5120MB" and "Usable memory: 4095MB".

I'm thinking my CPU is limiting that, as I have an AMD Athlon 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 5200+ (yes, I straight up copied that from the BIOS), and I'm thinking, what RAM limit does my CPU have (I couldn't find a website that would tell this).

Comment: Is the motherboard BIOS up to date?

Comment: @gronostaj yes, it's the Phoenix AwardBIOS 6.0PG

Comment: It is entirely possible that either the motherboard or CPU only support 4GB RAM, the CPU is from 2005 and discontinued in 2009... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athlon_64_X2

Comment: @Mokubai It's not the motherboard, as it detects the ram, so it is probably the cpu

Comment: Your memory is not limited by your processor.  Only three things explain the behavior you describe.  The first is you have a 32-but operating system.  The second the limitation is from the motherboard.  The third is the 1GB is hardware reserved.  The first and last are the only two that can be solved.  Even if it’s the CPU there isn’t a work around.  So make sure it’s not a 32-bit OS or hardware reserved

Comment: The RAM module side is told to the CPU by a few datalines alongside the memory interface. The CPU can easily read the module size but still not have enough lines wired up on the module to actually *use* the full size. It *could* be a motherboard problem. Sure it is more likely a CPU limit, but either could easily be the case.